# create a partition and assign to the rootusing terminal

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, gparted, root, memory-usage

I have a computer with dual boot system, windows 10 and Ubuntu. when i installed Ubuntu for the first time i did a mistake and give the root just 24 GB, that have been finished suddenly now, and i give the home all the remaining space (i don't remember how much it was but it is bigger than 150 GB). 
Yesterday i tried to install Cuda to my computer and in the middle of the installation i get an error and installation stopped.

When i try to download anything now i get this error:

```
Reading package lists... Error!
E: Write error - write (28: No space left on device)
```

**I tried to install GParted but i get the same error.**

when i run

```
sudo df -h
```

I get :

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            3,8G     0  3,8G   0% /dev
tmpfs           786M   20M  766M   3% /run
/dev/nvme0n1p7   24G   24G     0 100% /
tmpfs           3,9G  217M  3,7G   6% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5,0M  4,0K  5,0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           3,9G     0  3,9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0      129M  129M     0 100% /snap/vscode/77
/dev/loop1      3,8M  3,8M     0 100% /snap/gnome-system-monitor/70
/dev/loop3       36M   36M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1198
/dev/loop2      901M  901M     0 100% /snap/android-studio/70
/dev/loop4      2,3M  2,3M     0 100% /snap/gnome-calculator/238
/dev/loop5       15M   15M     0 100% /snap/gnome-characters/206
/dev/loop7       54M   54M     0 100% /snap/core18/782
/dev/loop10      13M   13M     0 100% /snap/gnome-characters/124
/dev/loop8       15M   15M     0 100% /snap/gnome-logs/45
/dev/loop6      391M  391M     0 100% /snap/clion/58
/dev/loop9      141M  141M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/74
/dev/loop13      35M   35M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/818
/dev/loop12     2,3M  2,3M     0 100% /snap/gnome-calculator/260
/dev/loop11     1,0M  1,0M     0 100% /snap/gnome-logs/57
/dev/loop14      35M   35M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1122
/dev/loop15     141M  141M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/82
/dev/loop16     272M  272M     0 100% /snap/pycharm-community/117
/dev/loop17      13M   13M     0 100% /snap/gnome-characters/139
/dev/loop19     3,8M  3,8M     0 100% /snap/gnome-system-monitor/54
/dev/loop18      15M   15M     0 100% /snap/gnome-logs/43
/dev/loop20     905M  905M     0 100% /snap/android-studio/71
/dev/loop22     366M  366M     0 100% /snap/clion/67
/dev/loop21      92M   92M     0 100% /snap/core/6531
/dev/loop24     4,2M  4,2M     0 100% /snap/gnome-calculator/352
/dev/loop23     906M  906M     0 100% /snap/android-studio/73
/dev/nvme0n1p9  167G   28G  131G  18% /home
/dev/nvme0n1p1   96M   53M   44M  55% /boot/efi
/dev/loop25     144M  144M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/23
/dev/loop26     295M  295M     0 100% /snap/pycharm-community/121
/dev/loop27     3,8M  3,8M     0 100% /snap/gnome-system-monitor/57
/dev/loop28     124M  124M     0 100% /snap/vscode/89
/dev/loop29     391M  391M     0 100% /snap/clion/61
/dev/loop30      90M   90M     0 100% /snap/core/6673
/dev/loop31      91M   91M     0 100% /snap/core/6405
/dev/loop33     125M  125M     0 100% /snap/vscode/87
/dev/loop32     141M  141M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/78
tmpfs           786M   16K  786M   1% /run/user/121
tmpfs           786M   64K  786M   1% /run/user/1000
```

From the result i think that the home has 131 GB empty space. My question is how can i take a part of the home partition and assign to the root partition without deleting anything from the root or the home data?

Edit:
I used the instruction in the comment and opened the GParted from the try ubuntu without install. 
this is the photo from the GParted:

[image: Gparted photo]

what should i do now?

Edit2:
I tried to unallocate memory from home as in the image, how can i merge it with the root now?

[image: unallocated space]

Comment: You can resize partitions with `gparted`. Note what you have to do it from live cd/usb, when this partitions not mounted

Comment: And is this completely fail proof?

Comment: NOTHING is "completely fail proof". `gparted` is reliable, but, as with all powerful tools, you can still shoot yourself in the foot.

Comment: Please run gparted and post your partition schema for a clear advice on how to assist you!

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen  I can't download GParted. I get error that there is no space

Comment: That's my point, asking OP to just run gparted isn't a very good advice IMO!

Comment: please run `which gpared` and lets see the result...

Comment: I told to run it from live cd/usb, where it can be installed

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen when i run which gparted nothing happens because i don't have it.

Comment: @LeonidMew what do you mean by live cd/usb?

Comment: Boot computer from Live USB/DVD (the one you used to install Ubuntu). Choose **"Try Ubuntu without installing"** Run Gparted. shrink and resize partitions as you want.

Comment: I mean run ubuntu from cd or usb. You still can download image to home partition and burn it

Comment: @user68186 do you mean that i need to insatll the wholeubuntu again. I  have installed Ubuntu on my computer last year using a usb, but it have been deleted from the USB. and in the case of downloading the system again isn't that mean that all my data will been lost?

Comment: No, not install again. Just run it from cd, and you will be able to use gparted then. As in comments above, choose "Try Ubuntu without installing" when boot from cd

Comment: No you don't need to install whole Ubuntu again. In that USB there was an option called **Try Ubuntu without Installing** That option will run Ubuntu from the USB without installing anything, as the name says. Gparted is included in the USB. When you **Try Ubuntu without Installing**  you will be able to run Gparted directly from the USB.

Comment: ok thanks for help, I will try that. Do i need to install the exactly same version of ubuntu, that i have in my computer,  in the usb before rebooting and calling try Ubuntu without installing?

Comment: Yes please use the same version of Ubuntu @ibda!

Comment: @ibda STOP! Do NOT try and reinstall Ubuntu. Follow user68186's instruction. Then take a screenshot of gparted when it's displaying your boot disk /dev/nvme0n1, and edit your question adding that screenshot, or use imgur.com and give us the link. Also, your boot times must be horrible, as you have a ton of snap applications installed. Best to remove them and use regular apt/synaptic/Software Center installs that are not snaps. Let me know when you have the gparted screenshot, and I'll be able to advise you properly.

Comment: @heynnema OP is not installing it's just bad use of terms...`the usb before rebooting and calling try Ubuntu without installing`

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen, I have edited the question now. when i turned the computer off and on again, i couldn't enter my old system again even before using the USB device.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91842/discussion-on-question-by-ibda-create-a-partition-and-assign-to-the-rootusing-te).